# handleChange in the parent component and child?

Tags: reactjs

What I am trying to do is:

on the parent component I have onChange=this.handleChange that it works fine for textInputs and it allows me to go to the next steps of my form but it doesn't setState of dropDowns whatever I do my dropdowns are empty and if I setState dropdowns on the child I am unable to trigger the handleChange on the parent thing that I need

```
    class CompanyInfo extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state =  {
        value: this.props.company,};
        this.handleChange = this.props.onChange.bind(this);
     }

      render() {
      return(
       <SelectInput value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}           
                floatingLabelText={messages.company[lang]}
                floatingLabelFixed={true}
                >
       {this.props.company.map((element) => {
        return <MenuItem value={element.Value} primaryText={element.Value} />})}           
      </SelectInput> 


parent:

        handleChange = (event) => { 
           console.log("test");
            const { stepIndex } = this.state; 
            const target = event.target;
            const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
            const name = target.name;

            var type = null;
            switch(stepIndex) {
                case 0: type='UPDATE_CINFO'; break;
                case 1: type='UPDATE_PINFO'; break;

                default: break;
            }
            this.props.dispatch(updateCurrentForm( type, { [name]: value } ));

            this.setState( this.state , () =>  this.validateFields()  )

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the prop of `handleChange` directly in the child component. And you also should control the state only at one place and use the state values as props in child components.

```
render() {
  const {handleChange, company} = this.props

  return(
   <SelectInput value={company}
            onChange={handleChange}           
            floatingLabelText={messages.company[lang]}
            floatingLabelFixed={true}
            >
...
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but it doesn't work, hanldleChange was  not triggered